# Trying to make python open a program via voice command

Tags: python

I'm trying to make something close to Alexa so I can have more liberty in making the commands and what they do. But I'm stuck on this error and can't figure why it doesn't remove the spaces from the string

```
listener = sr.Recognizer()
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
    
    programs = {
                'brave': 'brave.exe',
                'Chrome': 'chrome.exe',
                }
        
        def run_program(program):
                try:
                    spaces = int(program.count(' '))
                    print(spaces)
                    program.replace(' ', '', spaces)
                    print(program)
                    os.startfile(f"{programs[program]}")
                except Exception as er:
                    print(er)
                    talk("that program isn't in the list")
        def talk( text):
                engine.say(text)
                engine.runAndWait()
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be non-breaking space.
Try this:

```
replace('\xa0', '')
```

Comment: it didn't work spaces still there